# Kendo Grid with ASP.NET MVC, Custom Binding with Filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying the Kendo Grid with ASP.NET MVC, and I need custom binding according the document of http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding.

the problem is the document only have demo code about paging and sorting, but there is no information in filters exposed in the object of DataSourceRequest, so that I can not do custom binding with filters.

Anyone can help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part is missing from the link that you provided but a working sample can be found here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-custom-binding-for-sorting-paging-grouping-and-filters